# Type Constructor Overloading with Higher-kinded Types and Accessing the Type Constructor Parameter

Tags: scala, generics, overloading, higher-kinded-types

I have a value parameterless method that I want to overload with another method employing a higher-kinded type constructor.  I also want to make use of the type constructor parameter in the method body.  I also want to capture the class tag.  This is what I think should be possible:

```
trait SomeContainer[+A]
trait Foo[+A]

class SomeClass {
  // The simple variant
  def method[T <: AnyRef]: Foo[T]

  // Now the overloaded higher-kinded variant
  def method[F[T <: AnyRef : Manifest] <: SomeContainer[T]]: Foo[T] = {
    val classTag = manifest[T]
    // Do something with it
  }
}
```

However I do not have access to `T` at all here.  The aim here is to make the higher-kinded method here overload the non-higher kinded one `def method[T <: AnyRef]: Foo[T]`.  Have I reached a limitation of the language?  Is the non-higher kinded method signature far too open-ended making it impossible for the compiler to disambiguate the one from the other?  Is there a better more idiomatic approach to this sort of pattern of overloading on type parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload methods based only on type parameters at all, since they don't exist in JVM: so far as it's concerned, both methods are `def method(): Foo`. Technically a compiler could allow it by giving the overloaded methods different names in bytecode, but neither Java nor Scala do so.

> Is there a better more idiomatic approach to this sort of pattern of overloading on type parameters?

You could give one of the methods a dummy implicit parameter (there is a `DummyImplicit` type in `Predef` for this).